# Java Programming with GUI

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I am having problems with creating a GUI for an airport program. this is what needs to be done: This method displays the application's main window user interface. You can implement this interface in any way you like as long as you use Swing and Event processing (Listeners). For example, you could implement a series of buttons, one for each menu item.

These are the menu items:  
(1) Register a passenger,  
(2)Manage Passenger Itinerary,  
(3) Dispatch airplane.

You will exit the program by pressing the X button on the window.

The Register A Passenger option will do the following in order:

- First instantiate a passenger object filling in the information needed by the constructor. Then with that passenger object create an itinerary for this passenger by simply asking the user for activities and enqueue() each activity.
- Any number of activities can be created.
- Finally assign the passenger to an airplane & select the seat.

The Airplane class has methods to help perform these operations.

The Manage Passenger Itinerary will display a sub-menu with these options:  
(a) Display itinerary,  
(b) Add itinerary item,  
(c) delete an itinerary item, 
 
(d) move itinerary item,  
(e) quit.

The user must be prompted for their name and airplane number (see the Airplane class) then the actions from this sub-menu will be carried out on that passenger object. The Dispatch Airplane menu item dequeue() an airplane.

This means that the airplane, passengers and itineraries have all flown away to another airport and we no longer have to track them in our program.

When i compile this code i get a window with everything. but when i put : nameOfpassenger.getText(); Integer.parseInt(seatRow.getText()); Integer.parseInt(seatColumn.getText()); to get the input in the text field. I also need help when selecting "Register a Passenger" to be able to have the Passenger Registration Menu...same for manage a passenger. thanks This is what i got so far: (this is my first time using GUI)

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;
public class AirportOptions extends JApplet 
{
private static final long serialVersionUID = -827175473341332608L;

String[] options = {"Please Select An Option from the Menu: ","Register A Passenger","Manage Passenger Itinerary"};
private JTextField nameOfpassenger = new JTextField(10);
private JTextField seatRow = new JTextField(5);
private JTextField seatColumn = new JTextField(5);

private JButton button = new JButton("Dispatch The Airplane");

private JComboBox cbox = new JComboBox();
private JButton ok = new JButton("Ok");
private JRadioButton r_DI = new JRadioButton("Display Itinary");
private JRadioButton r_add = new JRadioButton("Add");
private JRadioButton r_del = new JRadioButton("Delete");
private JRadioButton r_mov = new JRadioButton("Move");
private JRadioButton r_q = new JRadioButton("Quit");




private int count = 0;

public void init() 
{

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        cbox.addItem(options[count++]);
    }


    cbox.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            ((JComboBox) e.getSource()).getSelectedItem();


        }
    });


    JPanel RadioButtons = new JPanel();
    RadioButtons.setLayout(new GridLayout(5,1));

    Container container_1 = getContentPane();
    Container container_2 = getContentPane();
    container_1.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    container_2.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    container_1.add(cbox);





    //PASSENGER REGISTRATION MENU

    JPanel jpTextField = new JPanel();
    jpTextField.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,1));
    jpTextField.add(new JLabel("Passenger Name: "),BorderLayout.WEST);
        jpTextField.add(nameOfpassenger,BorderLayout.WEST);
        nameOfpassenger.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.LEFT);
        add(jpTextField,BorderLayout.NORTH);
    jpTextField.add(new JLabel("Seat Row: "),BorderLayout.WEST);
        jpTextField.add(seatRow,BorderLayout.WEST);
        seatRow.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.LEFT);
        add(jpTextField,BorderLayout.NORTH);
    jpTextField.add(new JLabel("Seat Column: "),BorderLayout.WEST);
        jpTextField.add(seatColumn,BorderLayout.WEST);
        seatColumn.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.LEFT);
        add(jpTextField,BorderLayout.NORTH);        



    //MANAGE PASSENGER MENU
        RadioButtons.add(r_DI);
        RadioButtons.add(r_add);
        RadioButtons.add(r_del);
        RadioButtons.add(r_mov);
        RadioButtons.add(r_q);
        add(RadioButtons,BorderLayout.WEST);
        container_1.add(ok,BorderLayout.WEST);
        container_1.add(button);
    }




public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    run(new AirportOptions(), 400, 400);
}

public static void run(JApplet applet, int width, int height) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().add(applet);
    frame.setSize(width, height);
    applet.init();
    applet.start();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

}
```

Comment: Consider making your question as minimal as possible.

Comment: I posted all that to be sure that everyones knows what i need to do. what i am trying to do is to add PASSENGER REGISTRATION MENU and MANAGE PASSENGER MENU so that it only appears when i select it from the combobox menu. i should not get it when i run the program unless i choose it from the combobox menu.

Comment: i know it should be from the addActionListener but cant figure out how to do it.

Comment: Given that entire slew of words and characters contains not a single '?' prompts me to ask ..what ***is*** your question?

Comment: sorry, my question is how to we put the code, or where to we put ( which i think it will be in the addactionlistener) to be able to switch to a different window when selecting the Passenger Registration Menu?

Comment: And when we do that, i will need to create in that window new textfields...this is where i can not figure out how to do it.